# Capturing output from a command specified in Perl array

Tags: perl, command

I thought this must be simple, but I haven't found a viable solution.

The problem is as simple as this: I want to execute a system command and capture the output in Perl variable. The command is specified in Perl array (containing command and parameters, e.g. `@cmd = ('mycmd', '-opt1', 'arg1', 'val1')`).

I don't want to use forking, i.e. `open(FROM_KID, '-|')` is not an option. I know that if I had the command in a string I can achieve this with backticks. So perhaps this problem reduces to converting `@cmd` array into a string. In my case, the command arguments can contain spaces.

Is there a simple way to convert `@cmd` array into string that can be used with backticks, but such that all arguments are properly quoted? Also ideally without using any external libraries.

Thanks!!

Comment: First, using `system` or backtics will fork a child process - there's no way around that. You could do something like `$cmd = join(' ', map { s/'/\\'/g; "'$_'" } @cmd);` but `open` would probably be safer..

Comment: Re "I don't want to use forking", It's impossible not to fork. That's how all processes are created in unix, including when using `system`.

Comment: By forking, I meant implicit forking the Perl process itself that opening a pipe does, as I understood.

Comment: That's the same as the implicit forking done by `system` and backticks.

Comment: You should explain why you think you don't want to fork a subprocess, and why you don't want to use a Perl module

Comment: I want to be able to use the script under Windows as well, that was the reason. I don't care how the command is actually executed, but I noticed opening pipe via `open(FROM_KID, '-|')` does not work under Windows.

Answer (score 3):

You may be looking for [String::ShellQuote](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String%3A%3AShellQuote).  Note that only Bourne shell quoting is supported.

But backticks also perform an implicit fork, and if they in any way differ from the implicit fork of pipe open, I for one never noticed. :-\

Comment: The `String::ShellQuote` is third-party package, which I would like to avoid. We have an existing script that uses only core packages and supports Perl back to version 5.8. I just need to make it work under Windows with possibly not affecting the minimum requirements or adding dependency on packages not in core.

Comment: String::ShellQuote is pure Perl – you could copy the code from it.  But it will only work with Bourne shell, not with Windows' command.exe/cmd.exe.  On Windows, you'd need Win32::ShellQuote – or a recent enough version of perl that pipe open works. ;-)

Comment: The `Win32::ShellQuote` seems to be a place to borrow the code from. Thanks!